# Geodesics in an Alcubierrie Warp Drive metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics, warp-drives

The geodesics in an Alcubierrie Warp Drive metric are given by
$$\dot{t} = 1 \quad \dot{x} = X\dot{t} \quad y, z = \text{constant}$$ where $X = \dot{x}_s(t) f(r_s)$. Here $f(r_s)$ is a shape function given by

$$f(r) \equiv \frac{\tanh \frac{r+R}{\varepsilon}-\tanh \frac{r-R}{\varepsilon}}{2 \tanh \frac{R}{\varepsilon}}$$ where $R$ is the radius of the warp bubble and $\epsilon$ is the thickness of the warp bubble and $r_s = [(x-x_s(t))^2+y^2+z^2]^{1/2}$. Now I wish to solve the geodesic equation so naturally I have

$$x(t) = x_0 + \int^t \dot{x}_s(t) f(r_s) dt$$ Now, how does one evaluate this integral? Also, is $x(t)$ an increasing function of $t$ i.e. $x(t) \to \infty$ when $t \to \infty$ ? Also, what happens when we take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not the geodesic equations of the warp drive. They are the characteristic equations, which are straight lines. The integration is straightforward
$$X = c \ \ , \ \ x = Xt + \xi$$
where $\xi$ is the parameter on the x-axis where the characteristics are drawn. Those equations are solutions to the geodesic equations of the warp drive metric. The regulating form function assumes a top hat function in the limit $\epsilon \to 0$
$$
   \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f(r_s) =
      \begin{cases}
        1, & \text{for} \ \ r_s  \in [-R,R]\\
        0, & \text{otherwise}. 
        \end{cases}
$$
This demonstration is a very straightforward calculus exercise. Just remember that
$$\tanh(z) = \frac{e^{2z}-1}{e^{2z}+1}$$
and that the $\tanh$ function is bounded.

Comment: Can you please explain what are characteristic equations?

Comment: Characteristic equations are integral curves that form a tangent vector field in the direction where partial differential equations (PDE) solutions are constant. They are used in a method (called characteristic) to solve quasi-linear or hyperbolic PDE. For example, those integral curves in your question are the characteristics of the Burgers equation, which solve the vacuum Einstein equations for the warp drive metric.

Comment: When the integral curves of Burger's equation intersect, they form shock waves.